# Not able to render object in nextjs, error message map is not a function

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql, strapi

I am tryig to render data from STRAPI, using Graphql and nextjs.

###### I have an event Adapter which is working perfectly.

###### But when i try to render that data ON UI, it just give an error `event.map is not a function.`

###### Even though i can get the same result in the front-end, but the only problem is the map.

## conosle.log:

```
  const eventsAd = eventsAdapter(data);
  console.log("events data", eventsAd)
```

## Result - (IMG):

[image]

### Data result in the console - (IMG).

[image]

## Map that i created:

```
    <div>
      {eventsAd.map((event) => {
        return (
          <>
            <h1>{event.title}</h1>
          </>
        );
       })}
    </div>
```

## Error code:

[image]

##### Please advise me if i am doing something wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error it because you are trying to map an Object:

doing this should work for you:

```
<div>
  {eventsAd['Featured Events'].map((event) => {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>{event.title}</h1>
      </>
    );
   })}
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your answer.

Yes this worked, but i don't think adding the text (Featured Events) is a good apporch.

Isn't there any other way to make it work? 
I tried to user [0] it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: @Diavad change the property name of the object to featured_events and then just use eventsAd.featured_events.

Comment: @Divad yes it is not a good approach but you object it builds in that way

Comment: Thanks,

Which property  name shaould i change ?

Comment: And also what about the data inside the Featured Events? Featured Events is the category and the data inside belongs to the Featured Events.

Comment: @Divad no the property inside `Featured Events` is ok, you must change the `Featured Events` to `FeaturedEvents`, `featuredEvents ` or `featured_events `

Answer (score 0):

eventsAd is an object, so you can't use the map method. Map only works on arrays.
What you can do is

eventsAd["Featured Events"].map((item) => {});

or

eventsAd.International.map((item) => {});